# Bootstrap 2.3.2 - Don't use mobile layout for tablet portrait orientation

Tags: android, ios, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using `bootstrap 2.3.2` and testing on an iPad. My site looks great in landscape, but when switching to portrait it shows the mobile navigation and changes the layout of the site a bit.

I actually don't like it this way. I would prefer to only show the mobile navigation on phones. What do I need to change in the media queries of the `bootstrap-responsive.min.css` file in order to make this change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap 2+ has one breakpoint, you will find it in the bootstrap-responsive.css .. change it to match the desired device width you want to target, the default is max-width: 767px;

Comment: So, you are saying set that to a lower number to just target phones?